# Call linux command from a html page in Firefox or from Firefox extension

Tags: html, firefox, command-line

Is there any possibily that I can have a html page with button, that when the user click it, it will run linux command on the local machine?

If it is not possible, then is it possible to have a firefox extension that monitor a url, and if the url appear, the extension itself will run a linux command on the local machine?

The html page is run on Firefox on Linux platform.

Comment: It certainly is possible to make a Firefox add-on that runs shell commands. But there's no way you'll get me to install it...

Answer (score 1):

[I wrote such an extension a while ago](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.extensions/tree/browse_frm/thread/947e63c95c14b5a5?_done=%2Fgroup%2Fmozilla.dev.extensions%2Fbrowse_frm%2Fthread%2F947e63c95c14b5a5%3F&pli=1). The person who asked me to agreed to release it under an open-source license, and [here's a mirror](http://mozilla.doslash.org/cw/). Updating it to work under the latest version of Firefox is left as an exercise to the reader.